# Is there a synchronous version of change/enqueueChange that takes a batch/type?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm looking at making changes to the editor model without those changes being included in the undo history.
The way I've found to do this is via the enqueueChange method:

`editor.model.enqueueChange({ isUndoable: false }, writer => {`

However, this method does not keep my changes in order in the same way that the normal change method does:

`editor.model.change(writer => {`

When I switch a basic change call to `enqueueChange` in order to set the `isUndoable` flag to false, I experience changes being executed out of order - which is not an issue if I use the basic change call.

Is there a way I can mark a change set as `isUndoable=false` and keep those changes synchronous (ie, in order)?

Tried `editor.model.enqueueChange({ isUndoable: false }, writer => {` but changes queued this way do not always executed in order in the same way as changes made via `editor.model.change(writer => {`